# how to put 3 seaborn scatter plots under one another?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I want to combine all 3 seaborn scatter plots under one "frame".

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,15))
plt.subplots(3,1)
sns.scatterplot(x=train['Garage Area'], y=train['SalePrice'])
plt.show()
sns.scatterplot(x=train['Gr Liv Area'], y=train['SalePrice'])
plt.show()
sns.scatterplot(x=train['Overall Cond'], y=train['SalePrice'])
plt.show()
```

But it creates 5, the first 3 are small according to (7,15) size but the last 2 are different.

I suspect it should be

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,15))
fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,1)
ax[0] = fig.add_subplot(sns.scatterplot(x=train['Garage Area'], y=train['SalePrice']))
#plt.show()
ax[1] = fig.add_subplot(sns.scatterplot(x=train['Gr Liv Area'], y=train['SalePrice']))
#plt.show()
ax[2] =fig.add_subplot(sns.scatterplot(x=train['Overall Cond'], y=train['SalePrice']))
plt.show()
```

but all 3 plots are stuck in the last 3rd chart!

Answer (score 2):

The following is one way to do it:

- Create a figure with 3 subplots (3 rows, 1 column)
- Pass the respective subplot using `ax[0]`, `ax[1]` and `ax[2]` to the three separate `sns.scatterplot` commands using the keyword `ax`

---

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(7,15))

sns.scatterplot(x=train['Garage Area'], y=train['SalePrice'], ax=ax[0])
sns.scatterplot(x=train['Gr Liv Area'], y=train['SalePrice'], ax=ax[1])
sns.scatterplot(x=train['Overall Cond'], y=train['SalePrice'], ax=ax[2])
plt.show()
```